# Gmock ReturnRef does not return right value

Tags: googlemock

I try to using gmock, I set mock function return a listDetail with Lengh = 1, but when debug it away return listDetail with Lengh = 0 (it not return the value I set)

```
class CProcMock : public Cproc
{
public:
    MOCK_CONST_METHOD0(GetDetails, const std::vector<Cproc::Details>&());
};


std::shared_ptr<CProcMock> mock(new CProcMock());
std::vector<Cproc::Details> listDetail ;
Cproc::Details el;
listDetail .push_back(el);// listDetail size = 1;   
EXPECT_CALL(*mock, GetDetails())        
  .WillRepeatedly(ReturnRef(listDetail ));
```

Comment: Please help to make returnref return the right value

Answer (score 1):

function GetDetails must be a virtual function (gmock will overwrite it)